# Qual è il significato di "colmare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Storia della bambina perduta*, di Elena Ferrante, ho letto:

> Da qualche mese mi pareva che la distanza tra mia figlia e la figlia di Lila **si fosse definitivamente colmata**: collaboravano alla costruzione con precisione di gesti, e se Tina mostrava più estro e mi faceva domande spesso sorprendenti in un italiano limpido, sempre ben scandito, Imma era più decisa, forse più disciplinata, e l’unico suo svantaggio era una lingua contratta per decifrare la quale ricorrevamo tutti, spesso, alla sua amichetta.

Non capisco bene il senso dell'espressione "si fosse definitivamente colmata" in questo brano. Ho cercato il verbo "colmare" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a vedere a quale accezione corrisponda quello che appare in questo testo. Si riferisce forse all'[accezione 3 del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/colmare/), cioè "colmarsi" = "compiersi, avverarsi"? Il senso sarebbe che la narratrice sospettava da tempo che ci fosse una distanza tra sua figlia e la figlia di Lila e ultimamente le pareva che questo si fosse avverato. Tuttavia, questa spiegazione mi sembra un po' in contraddizione con il proseguimento della frase ("Imma era più decisa, forse più disciplinata, e l’unico suo svantaggio era...") e per di più c'è questo "ant." nel Treccani che mi fa dubitare ancora di più. Potreste aiutarmi a capire il significato di "colmare" nel passaggio precedente?

Comment: In inglese: to close the gap. ;)

Comment: @Charo, ecco come la interpreto io e senza scervellarmi poi tanto e usando un dizionario dei sinonimi e contrari. Vedo i due punti dopo "colmata" e le diverse azioni dopo tra le due tramite le quali "la distanza si fosse colmata" ovvero "si fosse riempita" di qualcosa (questo "qualcosa" sono le interazioni, dialogo e non, tra le due), in questo senso allora "vi era un vuoto tra le due"  ed ora non piú, o sempre meno, date l´interazioni tra loro.

Comment: Quindi é come se "la distanza si fosse accorciata", ove per "distanza" intendo quella "priva di interazione" tra loro due, quella "vuota" insomma,  il "vuoto" tra di loro semplicemente, e "si fosse accorciata" poiché sostituita, o man mano riempita, da renderla non priva di interazione e non vuota o meno vuota quindi, da "collaboravano alla costruzione..." e "se Tina mostrava più..." etc. Se ci fai caso mi rifaccio al significato proprio di colmare nel senso di "riempire" "in senso un po figurato e letterario..

Comment: stai leggendo un romanzo @Charo, devi figuratamente amalgamare le parole, non é un esercizio di grammatica tutto sommato :)

Comment: @mle: «devi figuratamente amalgamare le parole, non [è] un esercizio di grammatica tutto sommato»: potresti chiarire? La grammatica descrive la lingua italiana come è parlata e scritta, non è una roba che chi parla e scrive italiano onora quando deve fare un esercizio e per il resto ignora.

Comment: @Dag, caspiterina devo comprare una tastiera italiana e digito correttamente, pardon! Per il resto, è lungo il mio intervento per un commento e tanto meno è una risposta, puoi aprire una chat eventualmente, io purtroppo non posso, volentieri vorrei chiarire quanto intendo con la mia frase di prima! ;)

Comment: L'uso di “colmare” invece di “annullare” è davvero sorprendente: significano più o meno il contrario l'uno dell'altro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Colmare" significa riempire qualcosa con un liquido. Qui, in senso figurato (uso non raro di questo verbo), significa che la distanza è stata riempita, quindi non esiste più.

Comment: Be', “colmare una distanza” proprio non mi piace: il senso desiderato è il contrario di quello letterale (cioè, rendere massima quella distanza).

Comment: @egreg: Secondo me, anche "distanza" è usato in senso metaforico. È come ci si fosse un "buco" (in senso figurato) che adesso non c'è più.

Comment: @Charo Le doppie metafore vanno evitate con cura!

Answer (score 3):

In questo caso il significato è il 2.c del dizionario Treccani:

> *C. una lacuna*, compiere, procurarsi qualcosa di cui si sentiva la mancanza (soprattutto con riferimento a lacune di preparazione scolastica o di cultura); *c. un vuoto*, supplire in qualche modo persona o cosa che sia venuta a mancare: la sua scomparsa ha lasciato fra noi un vuoto che difficilmente si potrà colmare

Nel contesto significa che la separazione tra Tina e la figlia di Lila fosse finalmente terminata. Si tratta di una metafora un po' mista, per capirla forse aiuta immaginarsi la distanza come un fossato che separava le due bambine e che finalmente si è riempito lasciandole avvicinarsi.

Comment: Per cortesia la persona che ha votato -1 può commentare? Mi piacerebbe migliorare la risposta.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con te, @DenisNardin! Anch'io ultimamente ho ricevuto parecchi voti negativi e di solito non riesco a capire perché.